# Allure Framework: TestNG adapter incorrectly places @AfterMethod in report

Tags: allure

I`m using allure V1.4.8 +TestNG. It looks like TestNG adapter incorrectly places @AfterMethod in report - basically it places AfterMethod from test case into next testcase.

Here is the simple code:

```
    @Step("a test1")
    @Test
    public void Test1(){
    }

    @Step("a test2")
    @Test
    public void Test2(){
    }

    @Step("before method")
    @BeforeMethod
    public void beforeMethod(){     
    }

    @Step("after method")
    @AfterMethod
    public void methodCleanup()
    {   
    }
```

And here is the generated report:

```
<test-cases>
    <test-case start="1424347388060" stop="1424347388730" status="passed">
        <name>Test1</name>
        <steps>
            <step start="1424347388011" stop="1424347388014" status="passed">
                <name>before</name>
                <title>before test</title>
                <attachments/>
                <steps/>
            </step>
            <step start="1424347388036" stop="1424347388036" status="passed">
                <name>beforeMethod</name>
                <title>before method</title>
                <attachments/>
                <steps/>
            </step>
            <step start="1424347388067" stop="1424347388067" status="passed">
                <name>Test1</name>
                <title>a test1</title>
                <attachments/>
                <steps/>
            </step>
        </steps>
        <labels>
            <label name="host" value=""/>
            <label name="thread" value=""/>
        </labels>
    </test-case>
    <test-case start="1424347388747" stop="1424347389056" status="passed">
        <name>Test2</name>
        <steps>
            <step start="1424347388739" stop="1424347388739" status="passed">
                <name>methodCleanup</name>
                <title>after method</title>
                <attachments/>
                <steps/>
            </step>
            <step start="1424347388746" stop="1424347388746" status="passed">
                <name>beforeMethod</name>
                <title>before method</title>
                <attachments/>
                <steps/>
            </step>
            <step start="1424347388750" stop="1424347388750" status="passed">
                <name>Test2</name>
                <title>a test2</title>
                <attachments/>
                <steps/>
            </step>
        </steps>

     </test-case>
</test-cases>
```

Answer (score 1):

It's problem of TestNG adaptor. In our adaptor we use [ITestListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/ITestListener.html) listener and `onTestSuccess`, `onTestFailure`, `onTestFailedButWithinSuccessPercentage` and `onTestSkipped` methods to mark test as finished. But TestNG call the methods **before** `@AfterMethod`.

I don't know is there a way to handle *befores* and *afters* (maybe we can use other listener, an example [IInvokedMethodListener](http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/IInvokedMethodListener.html)). You can investigate this problem and send us pull request.

Hope it helps

### Update

New Allure TestNG integration has support for test fixtures. So you need to upgrade to Allure 2. For more details see the docs https://docs.qameta.io/allure/2.0/#_testng

Comment: I am facing the exactly same issue. I dont have much knowledge about the listners, could you please suggest me what should I do right now to solve this problem.