# Allure reports. Screenshots are added to wrong reports using AfterMethod

Tags: automated-tests, testng, allure

On my project I have maven and TestNG tools. 
And I'm trying to add screenshots to Allure reports.
If I call the method with "@Attachment" annotation directly from my tests, everything is okay.

But if I call it in "@AfterMethod" part, the screenshots are added to wrong reports and are mixed up.

In both cases screenshots are generated and saved on the disk correctly.

I've already seen the question here: [Allure Framework: TestNG adapter incorrectly places @AfterMethod in report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28606521/allure-framework-testng-adapter-incorrectly-places-aftermethod-in-report)

And I guess, my difficulties might be because of TestNG adaptor.

What is the correct way of calling the  "@Attachment" method? 
What adaptor do I have to use in order to avoid this problem? 
Maybe someone could provide me with example of using ITestListener to make screenshots only if a test is failed?

Answer (score 5):

I've had similar problem with Allure+TestNG and solved it by implementing **IHookable** interface by my BaseTest class. Implementing its run() method you just need to tell TestNG to run test as usual but catch exceptions to take a screenshot in case of any

Javadoc tells that:

> run() method will be invoked instead of each @Test method found.  The invocation of the test method will then be performed upon invocation of the callBack() method of the IHookCallBack parameter.

Code snippet looks like:

```
public class BaseTest implements IHookable {

    @Override
    public void run(IHookCallBack callBack, ITestResult testResult) {

        callBack.runTestMethod(testResult);
        if (testResult.getThrowable() != null) {
            try {
                takeScreenShot(testResult.getMethod().getMethodName());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    @Attachment(value = "Failure in method {0}", type = "image/png")
    private byte[] takeScreenShot(String methodName) throws IOException {
        return getWebDriver().getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
    }
}
```

Note, that u cannot use testResult.isSuccess() yet, because test method result execution is unknown yet and it has "RUNNING" status at that moment

This will take a screenshot immediately after exception caught and will place it into the right test-case of in allure report

Answer (score 1):

I too had the exact same problem with a Maven / TestNG project, where @AfterMethod was failing to successfully attach the screen capture.  The above solution from Illia worked PERFECTLY for me.  Thank you Illia!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](//stackoverflow.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Stack Overflow way of saying thank you.